# Can't connect to Docker based Cassandra container - "All host(s) tried for query failed"

Tags: java, cassandra

I'm attempting to create a simple Java app that can connect to Cassandra running inside of a Docker container running on my local machine. For the life of me I cannot get it to connect to the container!

I'm starting my container like this.

```
docker run -p 9042:9042 cassandra:latest
```

My Java code isn't super fancy..

```
   private Cluster cluster;
    private Session session;
    String serverIP = "localhost";

    String username = "cassandra";
    String password = "cassandra";
    String keyspace = "DefaultKeyspace";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CassandraTest cassandraTest = new CassandraTest();
        cassandraTest.connect("localhost");
    }

    public void connect(String node) {

        try {
            String username = "cassandra";
            String password = "cassandra";
            String keyspace = "DefaultKeyspace";

            cluster = Cluster.builder()
                    .addContactPoints(serverIP).withCredentials(username.trim(), password.trim())
                    .build();

            session = cluster.connect(keyspace);

            //  createSchema();
            Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();
            System.out.println("Connected to cluster:" + metadata.getClusterName());
            for (Host host : metadata.getAllHosts()) {
                System.out.println("Datatacenter: " + host.getDatacenter()
                        + "; Host: " + host.getAddress() + "; Rack: "
                        + host.getRack());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        getSession();
        createSchema();
    }
```

But no what what I do I keep getting this..

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:220)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1231)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:158)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:246)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:279)
    at CassandraTest.connect(CassandraTest.java:37)
    at CassandraTest.main(CassandraTest.java:27)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't use this Cluster instance because it was previously closed
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1213)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:158)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:246)
    at CassandraTest.getSession(CassandraTest.java:56)
    at CassandraTest.connect(CassandraTest.java:51)
    at CassandraTest.main(CassandraTest.java:27)
```

I've tried to use the docker host IP as well. How do I get it to connect??

Comment: you need to look inside Docker container into file `system.log` - it looks like something happens during initialization - see erorr `unconfigured table schema_keyspaces`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ip address of your docker-machine as cassandra host. If cassandra has come up clean, you should be able cqlsh into it using docker-machine ip address.

```
$ docker-machine ip
123.456.78.99
$ export CQLSH_HOST=123.456.78.99
$ cqlsh -u cassandra

Password:
Connected to Test Cluster at 123.456.78.99:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.6 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
cassandra@cqlsh>
```

So in your code, instead of using localhost, try using the docker-machine ip